# The name 'Master' does not exist in the current context

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to get a reference to a control in master page from an .ascx control in client-side jquery. I get error "The name 'Master' does not exist in the current context'". Please help. Thanks

```
<script>
function InitiateAjaxRequest(arguments) {
    var ajaxManager = $find('<%= (Master.MasterAjaxManager).ClientID %>');
    ajaxManager.ajaxRequest(arguments);
}
</script>
```

Comment: please provide a mvce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by creating a public `Site` property in the code behind of the User Control. `Site1` is the name of your Master Page.

```
public Site1 master;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    master = (Site1)Page.Master;
}
```

Then you can access it in the ascx like this:

```
<%= master.xxx %>
```

Or without changing the code behind file:

```
<%= ((YourNameSpace.Site1)Page.Master).xxx %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. What namespace is Site in ? When I add 'public Site master;' Visual Studio only finds 'System.Security.Policy'

Comment: It's not in any namespace, it is the class name of the Master page `public partial class Site1 : System.Web.UI.MasterPage`. Updated my answer to make it more clear.